# How to get first script from gameobject while having propery : Unity

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, get

I would like to get the first script in an gameobject, and still be able to set and get proper's of it.
I'm coding in c# in unity
I have tried "GetComponents(typeof(MonoBehaviour))" , "MonoBehaviour[] scripts = gameobject.GetComponents()" and other methods but all of that methods does not let you set and get

I dont know if it is even possible, and if it is not  a i work around would be nice.
Thanks

(If you need more info about this please comment and ill try to answer)

Comment: is the script that you are trying to get is a component ? aka MonoBehaviour

Comment: Welcome new user.  It's just `GetComponent<TheClassName>()`  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change properties of any Component (Unity Component or Script) by getting a reference to the Component and using that.

Assuming that the component is actually on your GameObject:

```
ComponentType component = GetComponent<ComponentType>();
component.RandomProperty = randomValue;
```

Example:

```
Rigidbody rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
```

You can use `GameObject.AddComponent<ComponentType>();` to Add a component.

Any component needs to derive from MonoBehaviour in order to be able to attach to a GameObject.

See:

[GameObject.GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

[GameObject.AddComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html)